# Exposed Filters conflicting with other views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have run into this weird issue when using the exposed filters.

Consider I created two views
1. List of published nodes and its fields of a content type X. Exposed Filters are title(textfield), body(textfield) and status(selectbox)
2. List of unpublished nodes and its fields of a content type X. Exposed Filters are title(textfield), body(textfield) and authorname(autocomplete)

I have set the exposed filters to remember the last selection done by user.

Please don't think why can't I give a filter for published and unpublished instead of creating two views. That is the requirement.
I created two menu items to show them in two different pages.

When I apply filters on page 1, it will give me the results I searched for.

Now when I click on page 2, the filters applied in page 1 are automatically applied on page 2.
When I change anything on page 2 and g to page 1, it will take the values from page 2.
When I select some value for status on page 1 and go to page 2, it is resetting the value of authorname to empty. Same applies when I did it in reverse order. When I choose some authorname and apply on page 2 and then go to page 1, it will reset the status I have selected earlier on page 1.

I was trying to find the root cause with no success. Could someone please let me know how can fix this and get them to work independent and also not reset the values on other views.

Thanks in advance
M

Comment: I also created two different views with a page display and not able to reproduce the issue. Could you explain more how you are using the views? Or either using blocks on separate pages? Which version of views you are using along with Drupal version please?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
As you said I am also trying to reproduce the same issue on a complete new fresh instance and not able to reproduce. Seems like there are modules that are interfering here for my site.

But after all I wonder is why would any module interfere with the session management(not some javascript on client side) which is done for this scenario. 

I am using Drupal 7.54 and Views 7.x- 3.15 by the way.